# Speed of light in vacuum in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, terminology

In special relativity, the speed of visible light is defined as a constant.

But visible light is only a small part of the electromagnetism field. So why?

Comment: Why what? All photons travel at the speed of light, whether or not in the visible part of the spectrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, @EddyKhemiri, as @almagest wrote it isn't just visible light, but rather that all electromagnetic waves moving through a vacuum travel at $c$. Also- just a pet peeve, but remember that this is the speed in a vacuum; it can be slower in different mediums.